# border-radius issue CSS

Tags: css, border

Having a bit of an issue with border-radius. I have successfully rounded off my rectangle, but I am having an issue with rounding the hover that I have placed over it. You will see in the top and bottom corners of the rounded rectangle the hover itself is not rounded and is actually a rectangle. I have tried rounding it but it rounds the center as well. I know this probably doesn't make sense but you will understand by looking here: http://jsfiddle.net/hCg3J/

All I want to do is to have each selection highlight the whole of that area, and not stick out.

HTML:

```
<ul class="pageitem">
    <li class="list" style="border-top:none;"><a href="iphone4.html";><span class="name">iPhone 4/4S</span><div class="arrow"></div></a></li>
    <li class="list"><a href="iphone3.html";><span class="name">iPhone 3G/3GS</span><div class="arrow"></div></a></li>
    <li class="list"><a href="ipod.html";><span class="name">iPod Touch</span><div class="arrow"></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.pageitem {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    behavior: url(/border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 8px;
    position:relative;
    zoom: 1;
    -moz-border-radius: 8em;
    -khtml-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: #878787 solid 1px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 3px 9px 17px;
    list-style: none
}
```

Comment: Try with Safari if you can, that is the browser I am having an issue with
EDIT: Also does not work in chrome

Comment: Please tidy up the fiddle. There is too much irrelevant code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add proper `-webkit-border-radius` in `.list:hover, name:hover` and adjust it to your needs.

Here is a [jsfiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/hCg3J/4/). What you need to do is to round only top-left and top-right corner for top element and bottom-left, buttom-right for the bottom element. I would suggest adding a special class for these elements.

UPDATE:

Actually as I suggested in comment I have added first-child and last-child selectors, [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hCg3J/7/)

```
.list:hover:first-child, name:hover:first-child {
     -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
}

.list:hover:last-child, name:hover:last-child {
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
}
```

Comment: I did this originally but as you can see it rounds off the corners in the middle too, so that for example the first selection, the bottom left and right corners are rounded.

Comment: see my updated answer. The solution I would suggest is using a special class for top /bottom element or use `first-child` and `last-child` selectors.